# pthreads hangs / stuck on pool->submit

Tags: php, pthreads, php-7

I'm trying to get Pthreads to work, but unfortunately with all of the outdated documentation it is really hard to figure out what is current and what has changed. As well as not getting any errors returned.

Running PHP7.2.0-dev with the latest version of pthreads and xDebug

Currently I have

```
<?php

$THREADS = 3;

class UptimeWorker extends Worker {
    public function start(?int $options = null) {
        return parent::start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_CLASSES | PTHREADS_INHERIT_CONSTANTS | PTHREADS_INHERIT_FUNCTIONS);
    }
}

class UptimeWork extends Threaded {

    private $i;

    public function __construct(int $i) {
        $this->i = $i;
    }

    public function run() {
        echo "I am ".$i.PHP_EOL;
        $this->setGarbage();
    }

}

$pool = new Pool($THREADS, UptimeWorker::class);

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    var_dump($i);
    $pool->submit(new UptimeWork($i));
}

echo "pre-shutdown".PHP_EOL;

$pool->shutdown();

echo "finished".PHP_EOL;
```

and the only output is `int(0)` from the first `var_dump` call in the `for` statement, from there the process just seems to hang, it doesn't exit and no further output is given.

What is going wrong here and what needs to happen in order for this to work?

Comment: Just some questions others are bound to ask, so might as well get them out of the way. Have you tried the code on php7 (no-dev) and without xDebug getting in the way? Did you build the library yourself or download for Windows (as there is no 7.2 version available for Windows)? And when you say "no errors" that includes the error.log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get two errors in your code, both in

```
 public function run() {
    echo "I am ".$i.PHP_EOL;
    $this->setGarbage();
}
```

First it should the `$this->i`  (simple typo)

Second is that `setGarbage` is not found as it's a property of `Collectable` (http://php.net/manual/en/collectable.setgarbage.php - Note: the manual documents the old PHP 5/API version 2 classes, this has changed to an interface for PHP 7/API version 3). Therefore you need

```
class UptimeWork extends Threaded  Implements Collectable {
```

to get access to `setGarbage()`. As `Collectable` is an interface, you also need to write the interface methods.

Here is your working code:

```
$THREADS = 3;

class UptimeWorker extends Worker {
    public function start(?int $options = null) {
        return parent::start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_CLASSES | PTHREADS_INHERIT_CONSTANTS | PTHREADS_INHERIT_FUNCTIONS);
    }
}


class UptimeWork extends Threaded  Implements Collectable {

    private $i;
    private $isGarbage = false;

    public function __construct(int $i) {
        $this->i = $i;
    }

    public function run() {
        echo "I am ".$this->i.PHP_EOL;
        $this->setGarbage();
    }

    public function setGarbage() {
        echo "Setting garbage ".$this->i.PHP_EOL;
        $this->isGarbage = true;
    }

    public function isGarbage() : bool {
        return $this->isGarbage;
    }

}

$pool = new Pool($THREADS, UptimeWorker::class);

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    var_dump($i);
    $pool->submit(new UptimeWork($i));
}

echo "pre-shutdown".PHP_EOL;

$pool->shutdown();

echo "finished".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: That's for PHP 5.6, API version 2, as documented in the PHP manual. This question is about PHP 7, API version 3. Check https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/examples/stub.php as well as the readme on the github repository.

Comment: Oh, I indeed looked at the manual, sorry then, have my upvote instead ;-)

Comment: Thanks - but it doesn't help that I linked the manual (that is out of date). I'll add a note!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you figured it out, I've tried so many different things and combinations, which, especially because of the incorrect documentation for different versions all around the web got me totally lost. I had basically given up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not a problem. Whenever you struggle it's best to go direct to the source when possible - in this case in GitHub. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to add another note here:

Turns out that with the **blackfire module** enabled it would just "hang" again without returning any errors, whereas disabling the blackfire module would actually return output / errors as expected.

So for those running into the same weird issue, if you have the blackfire module installed, **disable it**.